# Flutter provider error: When an inherited widget changes

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, provider, flutter-change-notifier

I don't think I'm dealing with providers very well. What is the correct code?

```
**import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/model/wether.dart';**

class UpdateWeather extends ChangeNotifier{

WeatherModel weathers = WeatherModel();
int temperature;
dynamic weatherImage;
String city;
dynamic weatherBack;


Future<void> updateUi(dynamic weatherData) async {
double temp =await weatherData['main']['temp'].toDouble();
 temperature = temp.toInt();
 var condition =await weatherData['weather'][0]['id'];
weatherBack = weathers.getWBackgroundImage(condition);
weatherImage = weathers.getWeatherImage(condition);
city = weatherData['name'];
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

The error message is like this.

> When an inherited widget changes, for example if the value of
>   Theme.of() changes, its dependent widgets are rebuilt. If the
>   dependent widget's reference to the inherited widget is in a
>   constructor or an initState() method, then the rebuilt dependent
>   widget will not reflect the changes in the inherited widget.
>
> Typically references to inherited widgets should occur in widget
>   build() methods. Alternatively, initialization based on inherited
>   widgets can be placed in the didChangeDependencies method, which is
>   called after initState and whenever the dependencies change
>   thereafter.
>
> The relevant error-causing widget was
>       MaterialApp
>   lib/main.dart:15
>   When the exception was thrown, this was the stack

This is the code that uses this provider.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/Provider/update_wearher.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/const.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/model/wether.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/view/navigator_dawer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static const routeName = '/lacation';

final locationWeather;

const LocationScreen({Key key, this.locationWeather}) : super(key: 
key);
@override
_LocationScreenState createState() => _LocationScreenState();
}

class _LocationScreenState extends State<LocationScreen> {
WeatherModel weathers = WeatherModel();

@override
void initState() {
 super.initState();
 Provider.of<UpdateWeather> 
(context).updateUi(widget.locationWeather);
}

@override
void setState(fn) {
Provider.of<UpdateWeather> 
(context).updateUi(widget.locationWeather);
super.setState(fn);
 }

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {

return Scaffold(
  body:Stack(children: <Widget>[
  Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.grey[850],
        image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage(Provider.of<UpdateWeather> 
     (context).weatherBack),
            colorFilter:  ColorFilter.mode(
                Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
            fit: BoxFit.cover),
      ),
      constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top : 200),
      child: Column(children: <Widget>[
         Image.asset(Provider.of<UpdateWeather> 
    (context).weatherImage,
            height: 120,
          width:120,
        ),
        // Image.asset(
        //   'assets/sun.png',
        //   alignment: Alignment.center,
        //   height: 120,
        //   width:120,
        // ),  
        SizedBox(height:30),
        Text('${Provider.of<UpdateWeather>(context).temperature}°',
        style: ktextStyle,
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height:10
        ),
        Text('${Provider.of<UpdateWeather>(context).city}',
        style: ktextStyle,)
      ],
      ),
    ),
    Positioned(
      child:AppBar(
       actions: <Widget>[
         IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.near_me),
          onPressed: () async {
            var weatherData = await weathers.getLocationWeather();
           Provider.of<UpdateWeather>(context). 
  updateUi(weatherData);
          })
       ],
    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
    elevation: 0,
  ),)
  ],
  ),
  drawer: Theme(child: NavigatorDrawer(),
    data: Theme.of(context).
    copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.2)),
  )
  );
 }
 }
```

Comment: Hi @hyesujo, from your error message it looks like the `UpdateWeather` provider may be initialised in the wrong place somewhere in your code, could you post the code that uses this provider?

Comment: @giles-correia-morton  tankyou 
I uploaded the code

Comment: @ giles-correia-morton Thank you very much. I'll do as you told me after work.

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my slow reply but I believe the below is how you should be structuring your screen. The error is coming from the fact that there is no defined provider called `UpdateWeather` in your widget tree above `LocationScreen` so you need to define one using `ChangeNotifierProvider`. (You can also use other providers but by looking at `UpdateWeather` it feels like `ChangeNotifierProvider` is a good fit.) Then you can add a `Consumer` of type `UpdateWeather` below the provider and it will automatically rebuild the screen when `notifyListeners()` is called in `UpdateWeather`.

Please note the use of darts `..` operator in the `create` call of `ChangeNotifierProvider` which ensures the `updateUI` method is called as the screen is built. This also allows us to make the whole screen stateless as the provider handles changes to state now.

Additionally you can also replace all the `Provider.of<UpdateWeather>()` references with `weather` as the provider is returned by the `Consumer<UpdateWeather>`.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/Provider/update_wearher.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/const.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/model/wether.dart';
import 'package:geo_app/view/navigator_dawer.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class LocationScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  static const routeName = '/lacation';
  final locationWeather;
  final WeatherModel weathers = WeatherModel();

  LocationScreen({Key key, this.locationWeather});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider<UpdateWeather>(
      create: (context) => UpdateWeather()..updateUi(locationWeather),
      child: Consumer<UpdateWeather>(
        builder: (context, weather, _) => Scaffold(
            body: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Colors.grey[850],
                    image: DecorationImage(
                        image: AssetImage(weather.weatherBack),
                        colorFilter: ColorFilter.mode(
                            Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), BlendMode.dstATop),
                        fit: BoxFit.cover),
                  ),
                  constraints: BoxConstraints.expand(),
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 200),
                  child: Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Image.asset(
                        weather.weatherImage,
                        height: 120,
                        width: 120,
                      ),
                      // Image.asset(
                      //   'assets/sun.png',
                      //   alignment: Alignment.center,
                      //   height: 120,
                      //   width:120,
                      // ),
                      SizedBox(height: 30),
                      Text(
                        '${weather.temperature}°',
                        style: ktextStyle,
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        '${weather.city}',
                        style: ktextStyle,
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  child: AppBar(
                    actions: <Widget>[
                      IconButton(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.near_me),
                          onPressed: () async {
                            var weatherData =
                                await weathers.getLocationWeather();
                            weather.updateUi(weatherData);
                          })
                    ],
                    backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
                    elevation: 0,
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
            drawer: Theme(
              child: NavigatorDrawer(),
              data: Theme.of(context)
                  .copyWith(canvasColor: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(0.2)),
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```